# Remove Selected Range LBA

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors

My HDD sounds like "click of death" on a specific range of LBA (which i check by tool). The HDD sounds very bad when accessing data on that range (imaging when you are using an application and suddenly, the application not response and the hdd start clicking).

So I want to remove that range **manually** from my disk (to prevent from using it in future)

My only solution is create that range as a new partition and do not use it. But the amount of data before that range is about 20GB (which have the highest performance on the disk, which should be used for installing OS, so i do not want to waste it).

Is there any tool(s) that can help me dealing with this problem?

Comment: What OS and/or file system are you using?

Comment: @cybernard: Windows, but i can plug it to others OS (Mac, Ubuntu, Windows) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not block access, but there are options.
Windows with ntfs or FAT16 or FAT32

chkdsk /r c: 
from the commmand prompt.  Say yes to do this after reboot.  Wait till you have hours of spare time.  For example, just before you go to bed, reboot verify the chkdsk is running and then go to bed.  All of the mentioned file systems have a "bad block" flag that will prevent the OS from using the bad sectors.

**Downside** if you ever move the partition the bad sectors will still be an issue.  Increasing the partition will not be an issue.

---

The next best answer is a specialized tool.  mhdd or Spinrite will both interact with the hard drives SMART function and cause the bad sectors to be completely hidden.  Both of these tools are highly advanced and can sometimes even recover the corrupted data.  The biggest downside is if you have more than >50-100 bad sectors it could take days for the process to complete.

Caution:  The hard drive has a limited number usually only a few hundred spare sectors and it is quite possible to run out.  After they run out the hard drive can not hide any additional bad sectors.  However, mhdd or spinrite in some cases can revive the sectors.

I have had a hard drive run for 700 hours.